# Factor the expression completely $x^{5/2} - x^{1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I factored out the $x^{5/2}$ and was left with $x^{5/2} (x^{-4/2}-1)$.

The answer in the book is $x^{1/2} (x+1)(x-1)$.

What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is ambiguous in terms of a full factorisation - if you are allowed $\frac 12$ as an index you can do $$x^{\frac 12}(x+1)(x-1)=x^{\frac 12}(x+1)(x^{\frac 12}+1)(x^{\frac 12}-1)$$

This is what you get if you set $y=x^{\frac 12}$ at the start to change all the exponents to integers, so the problem becomes: factorise $y^5-y$ and you get: $$y^5-y=y(y^4-1)=y(y^2+1)(y^2-1)=y(y^2+1)(y+1)(y-1)$$

---

Note: this further comment is less straightforward, but raises the question "what do you mean by a complete factorisation" rather more radically.

For a bit of fun, if you are allowed arbitrary fractions as indices you can do things like $$x+1=(x^{\frac 13}+1)(x^{\frac 23}-x^{\frac 13}+1)$$

which imitates $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$. For any odd $r$ you can set $a^r=x$ and obtain a factorisation of $x+1=a^r+1$ by extracting the factor $a+1$. For $x-1$ you can do something similar for any positive integer $r$.

so although the first form is probably the "obvious" one to go for, the question is not entirely well posed.

Comment: Dear Mark, This question is tagged algebra-precalculus. Though I understand where you're getting at, this might confuse the OP. Regards,

Comment: Mark's point is actually quite a sound one. Usually, factorisation questions deal with integer exponents (and expect answers using integral exponents). But once you allow non-integral exponents, all bets are off. The question is ill-posed.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar My first suggestion uses powers which are used in the "official answer" but is a factorisation into more factors. If you set out to solve the problem by putting $y=x^{\frac 12}$ to make all the exponents integral, this is the one you'd get.

Comment: @MarkBennet Dear Mark, I understand that; you've made a valid point. I have also +1'd your answer. In concern for the OP, however, I commented above, saying that it might confuse the OP. Regards,

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I've edited to something I hope is a bit better and less likely to confuse.

Comment: @MarkBennet I like the edit. I can't +1 it again, so I'll remark - good answer!

Answer (score 5):

$$x^{\frac52}-x^{\frac12}=x^{\frac12}\left(x^2-1\right)=x^{\frac12}\left(x-1\right)(x+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

$x^{\frac{5}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^{\frac{4}{2}} - 1)= x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^2 - 1) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1)(x-1)$

The last factorisation uses $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{5/2}-x^{1/2}=x^{1/2}x^{2}-x^{1/2}=\\
x^{1/2}(x^2-1)$$
Since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, let $a=x$ and $b=1$ (note that $1^2=1$). What do you get?

Comment: What is the best way for me to determine the value of the exponent inside the parentheses after I have taken out x^1/2

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla It is trivial; use the fact that $x^a\times x^{b}=x^{a+b}$ (the power rule). In this case, since $\dfrac{5}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{4}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}+2$, the above equation is obtained.

Comment: You mean 1/2 not 5/2 since 5/2 is the larger one?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla I do not comprehend. Please be more specific.

Comment: 5/2 is the larger exponent while as 1/2 is the smallest. I need to take out the smallest common factor?

Comment: I see my mistake. Thank You.

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla Yes, you are to factor out the smallest common factor, **not** the largest, else you will end up with a complicated expression.

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla No problem. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

try replacing $x^{1/2}$ with $t$, perform the factoring, then back replace $t$ with $x^{1/2}$

the first step would be...
$$x^{5/2} - x^{1/2} = x^{5\cdot\frac{1}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}= (x^{\frac{1}{2}})^5 - x^\frac{1}{2} = t^5 - t$$

you can complete the other steps.